# Deploy Database to Azure VM - but not on a Classic VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment, azure-virtual-machine

When using a VM(classic) , i am able to Deploy my SQL Server DB to Azure VM, by simply clicking onto it from the Tasks list:

[image: Deploy DB to Azure VM ( classic )]

I then simply choose the resource Group and then the VM name:

[image]

But now, i created a new VM (not a CLASSIC one), and it doesnt show in the list because the new VMs do not belong to a Resource group

So, how can i  manage to Deploy my DB to Azure VM (possibly without extracting the dacpac):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Migrate a SQL Server database to SQL Server in an Azure VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-migrate-onpremises-database/) lists all the methods to do the job. You can use [Backup to file and copy to VM and restore](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-migrate-onpremises-database/#backup-to-file-and-copy-to-vm-and-restore) when you cannot use the Deploy a SQL Server Database to a Microsoft Azure VM wizard shown in your posts.